# Modeling Ideas for a dataset with a lot of zeros

Tags: python, machine-learning, model

I have a dataset on corporate strategy. The columns including following: hire_num_2000, hire_num_2001...hire_num_2020, company size, employee number, etc. This dataset has lots of zeros. For companies that have never hired before, I want to build a model, and predict their performance.

People have suggested using clustering, and finding similar companies, but the cluster result wasn't very good.

Any suggestions on modeling lots of zeros?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use some kind of interpolation technique.  See the link below for info on how to proceed.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(0.0, np.nan, -1.0, 1.0),
                   (np.nan, 2.0, np.nan, np.nan),
                   (2.0, 3.0, np.nan, 9.0),
                   (np.nan, 4.0, -4.0, 16.0)],
                  columns=list('abcd'))

df
```

Result:

```
     a    b    c     d
0  0.0  NaN -1.0   1.0
1  NaN  2.0  NaN   NaN
2  2.0  3.0  NaN   9.0
3  NaN  4.0 -4.0  16.0
```

Now...

```
df = df.interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
df
```

Result:

```
     a    b    c     d
0  0.0  NaN -1.0   1.0
1  1.0  2.0 -2.0   5.0
2  2.0  3.0 -3.0   9.0
3  2.0  4.0 -4.0  16.0
```

However, if you are really missing a lot of data, you're almost completely better off finding a better data set.  If you are trying to train a machine to learn something, and you're missing lots and lots of data points, the machine will simply not learn well, and thus it won't be able to make predictions, no matter how amazing the algo is!